# Moving Coil Galvanometer working

Tags: experimental-physics

I'm in high school and we have this half deflection experiment in our physics lab. I'm attaching the procedures and circuit. What principle does this work on.

[image]

Procedure
(a) Resistance of galvanometer by half deflection method

Make the connections accordingly as shown in circuit diagram.

1.See that all plugs of the resistance boxes are tight.
2.Take out the high resistance (say 2000 Ω) from the resistance box R and insert the key K1 only.
3.Adjust the value of R so that deflection is maximum, even in number and within the scale.
4.Note the deflection. Let it be θ.
5.Insert the key also and without changing the value of R, adjust the value of S, such that deflection in the galvanometer reduces to exactly half the value obtained in step 5 i.e., θ/2.
6.Note the value of resistance S.
7.Repeat steps 4 to 7 three times taking out different values of R and adjusting S every time.
(b) Figure of merit
Take one cell of the battery (battery eliminator) and find its E.M.F. by a voltmeter by connecting +ve of the voltmeter with +ve of the cell and -ve of voltmeter with -ve of the cell. Let it be E.
Make connections as in circuit diagram.
Adjust the value of R to obtain a certain deflection 0 (say 30 divisions) when the circuit is closed.
Note the values of resistance R and deflection θ.
Now change the value of R and note the galvanometer deflection again.
Repeat the steps 9 to 13 with both cells of the battery with different voltages like 2, 4, 6, 8, volts from battery eliminator.

(b) Figure of merit
1.Take one cell of the battery (battery eliminator) and find its E.M.F. by a voltmeter by connecting +ve of the voltmeter with +ve of the cell and -ve of voltmeter with -ve of the cell. Let it be E.
2.Make connections as in circuit diagram.
3.Adjust the value of R to obtain a certain deflection 0 (say 30 divisions) when the circuit is closed.
4.Note the values of resistance R and deflection θ.
5.Now change the value of R and note the galvanometer deflection again.
6.Repeat the steps 9 to 13 with both cells of the battery with different voltages like 2, 4, 6, 8, volts from battery eliminator.
7.Find the figure of merit k using the formula.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The underlying principle is Ohm's law,  e.m.f. = current $\times$ resistance.

In part (a), you start with the resistance $R$, and there is enough current to give a full-scale deflection of the galvanometer.  You then introduce $S$ and halve the deflection, which means there is half the current.  By Ohm's law, you must have doubled the resistance.
That is, the equivalent resistance of the galvanometer and $S$ in parallel must be equal to $R$.  If you set $S || G = R$ and solve for $G$, you get the resistance of the galvanometer.

In part (b), you first measure the open-circuit voltage of the battery (there is essentially no current flowing because the voltmeter has extremely high resistance).  Then you set the current to a particular level by adjusting $R$, and calculate $E/[(R+G)\theta]$.  The numerator is the open-circuit voltage, and the denominator is proportional to the voltage when current is flowing (by Ohm's law).  If the battery were ideal then its voltage would be the same whether or not a current was flowing, and $k$ wouldn't change with current.  But a real battery's voltage declines with current; this is often modeled as 'internal resistance' of the battery.